# How to run .sh file from anywhere on MacOSx

Tags: macos, unix

I have several utility programs that I need to run.  What I am doing write now is going to the bin directory of thee apps and running .\program.sh  to run them.  Obviously not practical to run it everywhere this way.  Putting the bin directory on my path would still not allow these scripts to be executed anywhere would it?  So how should a .sh file be run from another directory?

Comment: You need to [adjust the `PATH` environment variable](http://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Terminal and edit the `.bash_profile`

You can add:

```
export PATH=<path to script folder(s)>:$PATH
```

Now run

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

to update your terminal, then try:

```
which <scriptname>
```

If you see your script, all should be good!

Comment: but how would I then run the scripts?  program.sh ./program.sh

Comment: How would I execute the script?

Comment: <scriptname> from the Terminal.  Just use the name, and if you're not sure, it should have tab completion.

Comment: Oh I see.  Just retrace.sh should now run it.

Comment: Yup, hope that helped!  Keep in mind that the PATH is order dependent to, so when you run a command, it will look for the command in the folder in the order specified by the PATH environment variable (to view  just run `echo $PATH`), meaning if you have 2 commands with the same name, the PATH order will determine which is run.